# python requests splitting certain data mismatch

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests, lxml

Trying to get data from a website but getting two data for some urls

for honda civic

`make = honda`

`model = civic`

for land rover

`make = land`

`model = rover`

where it shoud be

`make = landrover`
`model = rangerover`

tried this :

scala.txt:

```
https://www.redbook.com.au/cars/details/2019-honda-civic-50-years-edition-auto-my19/SPOT-ITM-524208
https://www.redbook.com.au/cars/details/2019-holden-astra-rs-black-edition-bk-auto-my19/SPOT-ITM-524534
http://www.redbook.com.au/cars/research/used/details/2014-land-rover-range-rover-evoque-ed4-pure-tech-manual-my15/SPOT-ITM-410126
http://www.redbook.com.au/cars/research/used/details/2014-land-rover-range-rover-evoque-sd4-pure-tech-auto-4x4-my15/SPOT-ITM-410136
```

```
import lxml.html as lh
import pandas as pd
import html
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


cars = []
with open('scala.txt') as f:

    urls = f.read().splitlines()
for url in urls: 

    car_data={}
    headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
    page = (requests.get(url, headers=headers))
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

    car_data['url']=url
    if tree.xpath('//h1[@class="details-title"]/text()')[0]:
        full_car_name = tree.xpath('//h1[@class="details-title"]/text()')[0]
        car_data['naming'] = full_car_name
        print(full_car_name)
    car_data['id'] = url.split("SPOT-ITM-")[1].replace("/", "")
    car_data['year'] = full_car_name.split(" ")[0]
    car_data['make'] = full_car_name.split(" ")[1]
    car_data['model']= full_car_name.split(" ")[2]
    cars.append(car_data)
```

for first two it is fine , when the third url comes ther is multiple values

output :

```
{'id': '524208',
  'make': 'Honda',
  'model': 'Civic',
  'naming': '2019 Honda Civic 50 Years Edition Auto MY19',
  'url': 'https://www.redbook.com.au/cars/details/2019-honda-civic-50-years-edition-auto-my19/SPOT-ITM-524208',
  'year': '2019'}


{'id': '410136',
  'make': 'Land',
  'model': 'Rover',
  'naming': '2014 Land Rover Range Rover Evoque SD4 Pure Tech Auto 4x4 MY15',
  'url': 'http://www.redbook.com.au/cars/research/used/details/2014-land-rover-range-rover-evoque-sd4-pure-tech-auto-4x4-my15/SPOT-ITM-410136',
  'year': '2014'}
```

For land rover , `make should be land rover` and `model should be range rover`

Comment: please edit your post to include full `traceback`

Comment: @buran added traceback

Comment: the third link has no images. you need to handle such case, e.g. using try/except

Comment: @buran if i run a 100 url i am getting index out of range, but if i run small bunch there is no index of out range why ?

Comment: you get index out of range when you try to parse element that does not exists. e.g. in this case you try to get image href, but in third url there are no images. You run the same risk if year, make or model info is not present. Would you get error on ceratin bunch of urls depends on what info is there. If you are lucky all info you look for will be there, but that is not always the case.

Comment: @buran editied the q pl check.  in case of honda civic 


`make = honda model = civic`

and for `land rover = make = land ,                                                                        model = rover where it shoud be make = landrover`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199368/discussion-between-thor-is-and-buran).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `try/except`. There is no img for some of the elements. Hence when it tries to get the image_url from index `[0]`, there is nothing there. You are basically telling to grab the 1st element from an empty list:

**Skeleton for `try/except`**

```
try:
    <code to do something>
    <code>
    <more code>
    ...
except:
    <code to do something if the try fails/throws errors>
    ...
    ...
```

**So with the images:**

```
...    

car_data={}
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
page = (requests.get(url, headers=headers))
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

try:
    img_urls = tree.xpath('//div[@class="r-module"]/div[@class="csn-results"]/div[@class="content"]/a[@class="item"]//div[@class="photos"]//img/@src')
    img_url = tree.xpath('//ul/li/a/img/@src')[0]
    img_url = str(img_url)
    img_url = img_url
except:
    img_url = 'N/A'

    ...
```

Here is also some help in fixing your json key:values.
The reason you are getting those results is because you are splitting on the white space. And in the text/content, it's `land rover range rover`, not `landrover rangerover`. So when you split, it's returning `['land', 'rover', 'range', 'rover']`. And you are grabbing the elements in index 0 and 1, which is `'land'`, and `'rover'`.

Now IF the text was `'landrover rangerover'`, then you'd correctly get what you want. It would split `['landrover', 'rangerover']`, so then grabbing element in index positions 0 and 1 would work the way you want.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re
import json


cars = []
with open('scala.txt') as f:

    urls = f.read().splitlines()


for url in urls: 
    car_data={}
    headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
    page = (requests.get(url, headers=headers))
    soup = bs(page.content, 'html.parser')



    script = soup.find('script', text=re.compile("CsnInsights.metaData"))
    jsonData = json.loads(script.text.split('CsnInsights.metaData = ')[-1].rsplit(';',1)[0])

    make = jsonData['make']
    model = jsonData['model']
    car_id = jsonData['networkid'].rsplit('-',1)[-1]

    naming = soup.find('div', class_='heading').text.split(' ',1)[-1]
    year = soup.find('div', class_='heading').text.split(' ',1)[0]

    car_data = {'id':car_id,
                'make':make,
                'model':model,
                'naming':naming,
                'url':url,
                'year':year}

    cars.append(car_data)
```

**Output:**

```
print(json.dumps(cars, indent=4))

[
    {
        "id": "524208",
        "make": "Honda",
        "model": "Civic",
        "naming": "Honda Civic VTi-S Auto MY19",
        "url": "https://www.redbook.com.au/cars/details/2019-honda-civic-50-years-edition-auto-my19/SPOT-ITM-524208",
        "year": "2019"
    },
    {
        "id": "524534",
        "make": "Holden",
        "model": "Astra",
        "naming": "Holden Astra RS BK Auto MY19",
        "url": "https://www.redbook.com.au/cars/details/2019-holden-astra-rs-black-edition-bk-auto-my19/SPOT-ITM-524534",
        "year": "2019"
    },
    {
        "id": "410126",
        "make": "Land Rover",
        "model": "Range Rover Evoque",
        "naming": "Land Rover Range Rover Evoque SD4 Pure Manual 4x4 MY14",
        "url": "http://www.redbook.com.au/cars/research/used/details/2014-land-rover-range-rover-evoque-ed4-pure-tech-manual-my15/SPOT-ITM-410126",
        "year": "2014"
    },
    {
        "id": "410136",
        "make": "Land Rover",
        "model": "Range Rover Evoque",
        "naming": "Land Rover Range Rover Evoque SD4 Pure Tech Manual 4x4 MY15",
        "url": "http://www.redbook.com.au/cars/research/used/details/2014-land-rover-range-rover-evoque-sd4-pure-tech-auto-4x4-my15/SPOT-ITM-410136",
        "year": "2014"
    }
]
```

Comment: how to write multiple excepts ? can you help. like write two more excepts. for two more xpaths. just show me the skeleton

Comment: the skeleton is the same as the example I give above.